# How does IntelliJ IDEA store search index on disk?

Tags: intellij-idea, search, indexing

I know that for search capabilities IDEA builds inverted
index of all tokens (words).
For instance, for "Find in files" and regex search it uses
Trigram Index (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigram_search)
and [IDEA sources](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/indexing-impl/src/com/intellij/find/ngrams/TrigramIndex.java))

Also I know that this index could be really huge,
so it definitely must be stored on HDD,
because it can not fully fit into RAM.
And it should be rapidly loaded into RAM
when search action is executed.

I have found that they use externalization
(see [IDEA sources](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/util/src/com/intellij/util/io/DataExternalizer.java)) approach to [serialize
and deserialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) index data for implementation of indexes.

#### Questions:

1. Does IDEA cache index in memory, or loads index data for each search action?
2. If (1.) is true, how does IDEA decides what indexes to keep in memory and which should be cleared? In other words, which [cache replacement policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies) is used?
3. Where is the code in [repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) which stores and reads index on HDD?
4. (optional) What is the format of indexes stored on HDD? Is there any documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to post my answers in the same order

1. After going through the entire project we write all the forward and inverse indexes to disk. When a user edits a file in the IDE, they are changing the contents of the Document representation (stored in memory) but not the contents of VirtualFile (which is stored on disk). To deal with this there are large indices on disk that reflect the state of physical files (the VirtualFile representation), and for Document and PsiFile representations there is an additional in-memory index. When an index is queried, the in-memory index, being the most up-to-date, is interrogated first, then the remaining keys are retrieved from the main on-disk indices and the cache.
2. Indexes located on disk can be found in IDE system directories https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs
3. I suggest going through the usages of methods of com.intellij.util.indexing.IndexInfrastructure and  com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndex these classes are working with file paths and have methods for working with and reading from indexes.
4. Contents of /index directory are project dependant.

Additionally: If user edits a file, we don't create indices for it until we need them, for example until the value of a specific key is requested. If the findUsages command is called while a file is being edited, additional indexing occurs only at that moment. However, a situation like that is almost impossible, since files are written to disk quite frequently and global indexation is run on changes.